# Unexpected results when querying on FormattedID

Tags: c#, rally

I have built a custom integration that queries the API by formatted ID. In cases where there are duplicate IDs of different types (US181 & DE181), I'm often receiving only a single response back from the system, and that seems to be the wrong artifact. I'd like to search for Tasks, Stories, and Defects using formatted ID (either US181 or 181) and receive the appropriate result.

C# code below:

```
public static string FindArtifactByFormattedId(string formattedId)
    {
        string artifactRef = null;

        Request req = new Request("Artifact");
        req.Query = new Query("FormattedId", Query.Operator.Equals, formattedId.Remove(0,2));
        req.Workspace = rallyWorkspace;
        QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(req);
        if (queryResult.TotalResultCount > 0)
        {
            foreach(DynamicJsonObject djo in queryResult.Results)
            {
                if (djo["FormattedID"] == formattedId)
                {
                    artifactRef = djo["_ref"];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return artifactRef;
    }
```

Comment: What is the version of the .NET REST dll that you are using? Testing your example code I received the expected results for version 1.05 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a defect in our WSAPI. I have filed this internally so that it can be prioritized, until then you can you can always query on each individual artifact to look for a specific artifact by FormattedID.